# how to transfer a file over SSH with granados

Tags: c#, ssh, sftp

I have started developing a simple application that transfer my local files to a remote **SSH** server over SFTP.

My application is expected to do it programmaticly so i am planning to use **Granados** opensource SSH solution. In Granados test application there is a simple example like:

```
            SSHConnectionParameter f = new SSHConnectionParameter();
            f.UserName = "root";
            f.Password = "";
            f.Protocol = SSHProtocol.SSH2;
            f.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationType.Password;
            f.WindowSize = 0x1000;

            Reader reader = new Reader();
            Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            //s.Blocking = false;
            s.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 22));
            _conn = SSHConnection.Connect(f, reader, s);
            reader._conn = _conn;

            SSHChannel ch = _conn.OpenShell(reader);
            reader._pf = ch;

            SSHConnectionInfo ci = _conn.ConnectionInfo;
```

In Granados, I couldn't find any examples which tells how to send a file.

I think there must be a simple function such as `_conn.TransmitFile(sourcePath, destinationPath);` but I couldn't find any example.

Does anyone know how to send a file between servers over SSH by using C# with Granados library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To transmit data
reader._pf.Transmit(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(nextCommand), 0, nextCommand.Length);